# Morph object into another in Blender

Tags: blender, fbx, shrinkwrap

I have two .fbx models – human and daemon. The task is to morph from human to daemon with corresponding transform animations of limbs/head/body.
I'm trying to apply shrinkwrap modifier to human object, but ended up with nothing good looking because of different model's components, therefore I'm not sure if shrinkwrap approach is useful here. Maybe you can address some another technique?
You can see the human model selected in 
[hierarchy link here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSQzq.jpg)

Comment: If they have a matching vertex count you can [join them as shapekeys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34758/935). note that a similar [vertex order is also needed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2127/935), you have a few options to [sort vertices](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/misc.html#sort-elements).

Answer (score 0):

This would be difficult to do, i think you would need to manually create shapekeys, manually chenge the mesh and maybe generate some in between models, to shrink wrap upon. But most likely you will not able to make use of shrink wrap at all.. pure manual shapekeys. Manual would give the best control on how deformations apply (so horns dont become ears etc).